# Check whether EXEC('SELECT...') will run without error, without returning query results

Tags: sql-server

I want to dynamically build a query (which will always be a SELECT statement) within a string variable, pass it as an argument to EXEC(), and then:

-If the EXEC() statement encounters an error, proceed with my custom error handling.

-Otherwise, continue without actually selecting the results to my results pane (I'll be doing this often within a stored procedure, so the pane would easily get cluttered).

I tried a try/catch while toggling NOEXEC on and back off, expecting to see 'Zero division error encountered', but instead just seeing "Commands completed successfully."

```
DECLARE @sql varchar(max)
SET @sql = 'SELECT 2 / 0;'

BEGIN TRY
    SET NOEXEC ON;
    EXEC(@sql)
    SET NOEXEC OFF;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    PRINT('Zero division error encountered')
END CATCH
```

Basically I want the clutter-reducing benefit of NOEXEC, but if the query encounters an error, I want to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

NOEXEC does only compilation, it does not Execute.  The division never happens.

If you want division to happen, do this --

```
Declare @ans int

BEGIN TRY
    Set @ans = 2 / 0
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    PRINT('Zero division error encountered')
END CATCH
```